# Laravel cast Request to different Request

Tags: validation, laravel, casting

I have a three different forms that submit to the same controller in Laravel. Each form has its own validation rules stored in a Request. Here's an example of my code:

```
public function store($id, $type, Request $request)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'daily':
            $this->monthly($id, $type, $request);
            break;
        case 'monthly':
            $this->monthly($id, $type, $request);
            break;
        case 'yearly':
            $this->yearly($id, $type, $request);

    }
    return redirect(route('x.show', $id));
}


private function monthly($id, $type, MonthlyFormRequest $request)
{
    //store form
}
```

However, this doesn't work and throwns an instance error since `Request` isn't the same type as `MonthlyFormRequest` in the `monthly` method. Is there a way to cast the `Request` to `MonthlyFormRequest` or is there some other way to do it? I prefer to avoid declaring validation rules in the controller itself. What would be the best way to get a uniform `Request` type request in the store method and then use `MonthlyFormRequest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the type trough a request parameter and move the switch case to your request and preform the check there as such:

In your request:

```
   public function rules()
        {
          switch($this->type){
             case 'dailty':
                  return [
                           'field': 'required'
                         ];
                  break;
             case 'monthly':
                  return [
                           'field': 'required'
                         ];
                  break;
             case 'yearly':
                  return [
                           'field': 'required'
                         ];
                  break;
          }

      }
```

In your Controller:

```
public function store($id, YourCustomRequest $request)
{
    return redirect(route('x.show', $id));
}
```